# What is the Python equivalent of C types float, double and long?

Tags: python, c, floating-point, double, long-integer

What is the Python equivalent of these C types:

```
float
double 
long
```

I want to represent a `float` in the above three forms.

Comment: `float`, `double` and `long` aren't functions, they are *types*. And `long` is an *integer* type.

Comment: If you want single-precision floats, you might also look at `NumPy` and the `ctypes` module, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you mean *types*, not functions. In C, a `double` is just a double-precision `float` (meaning smaller numbers are represented more accurately). In Python, it's just a `float`. Similarly, a `long` is (was) just an `int` that stored larger numbers.

In Python 2, there is `int`, `long`, and `float`. However, Python automatically promotes `int` to `long` when it grows above `sys.intmax`. That means there is no point in ever using `long` in Python. It will turn into a `long` automatically when it needs to. A `float` is represented as a `double` internally.

The short answer is to just use `int` and `float`, and don't worry about the underlying implementation. Python abstracts that away for you.

You can convert an `int` to a `float` (and back) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

number = 45
real_number = 3.14159265359

number_as_float = float(number)
real_number_as_int = int(real_number)
```

See more about the standard Python types [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: You don't need the "on most platforms": a Python `float` is *always* stored as a C `double` internally (assuming that we're talking about CPython). Of course, what format that C double is depends on the platform, but it's almost always IEEE 754 binary64 on current mainstream platforms.

Comment: From the Python manual: `Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C; information about the precision and internal representation of floating point numbers for the machine on which your program is running is available in sys.float_info.` But I'll remove it from the post and just leave this comment. I feared if I didn't include "on most platforms" someone would point that out ;)

Comment: We don't, actually. :-) That comment may be outdated. Look at the CPython source, specifically `Include/floatobject.h`, and find the `PyFloatObject` structure. You'll see a `double ob_fval` field for the float value.

Comment: Actually, that bit of the docs is not outdated; it's simply wrong. :-) If I find enough energy, I'll submit a fix. `sys.float_info` is also based directly on the `DBL_EPSILON`, `DBL_MAX`, etc. macros; there's no facility built into the source for swapping out `double` for another floating-point type (though that would be cool).